# Cannot find my input in string using grep

Tags: grep

I've a string separated with commas where I want to find my input in that line:

`echo US | grep "US,CA,CH,JP"`

The output is empty!
How should I use grep to find my input in that string?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Swap the arguments of the commands:

```
echo "US,CA,CH,JP" | grep US
```

In:

```
echo US | grep "US,CA,CH,JP"
```

you are looking for the string (pattern) `US,CA,CH,JP` in the input string `US`, which is not matching expectedly.

Answer (score 14):

Unless you were expecting the commas to act like an "or" statement, in which case you just need to change the commas to pipes and use the `-E` option for *Extended* regular expressions:

```
echo US | grep -E "US|CA|CH|JP"
```

Or change the commas to newline characters:

```
echo US | grep "US
CA
CH
JP"
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use `$echo US | grep -i "US|CA|JP|CH"`

Instead of eco give it a list or something, where it can actually can go and look for patterns, instead of looking for them in "US"

Comment: You forgot `-E`.